# How do I check if a string does/doesn't consist of a set of conditions

Tags: regex, string, list, vim

I would like to check if a string consists of a set of condition:

p.e.

```
let myvar = '.....'  
if myvar doesn't contain:   

- 'cos'
- or 'sin'
- or 'tan'
- or 'log'
- or only contains of this: [0-9*/:-+<space>]
- or ... etc 

give an error message.
```

I would like to put all the conditions in a list and check if the string
has one of these conditions.
If the string has no one of these conditions, give error message.

Can anyone help me to find the correct regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the `match()` function

```
function! Test(s)
    if match(a:s, '\<\(cos\|sin\|tan\|log\)\>') < 0
        echo "functions not matched"
    endif
    if match(a:s, '^[0-9*\\\/:+\- ]*$') >= 0
        echo "only numerics and operators"
    endif
endf
```

Hope this sample of usage helps. Test it with

```
:call Test('123 * 38 - 04 : 7 + 1269')
:call Test('biological')
:call Test('log(x)')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the opposite:

```
^.*\(cos\|sin\|tan\|log\|[^0-9*\/:+ -]\)
```

matches if at least one of the terms `cos`, `sin` etc. or at least one character other than `0-9`, `*` etc. can be found in the string.

Therefore, it fails to match if the string only consists of the characters `0-9*\/:+ -` and/or doesn't contain any of the keywords you mentioned.

Comment: Vim does have lookahead assertions. You just don't need them here.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I still don't understand how to check myvar with the code you've written. Can you please give me an example how to check myvar? Note: myvar match when there are **only** `[0-9*\/:+ -]` characters or if myvar contains `cos\|sin\|tan\|log`

Comment: @Tim: but  how to check it? `if myvar ^.*\.*\(cos\|sin\|tan\|log\|[^0-9*\/:+ -]\)` ??